# Python raw string "r" flag equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, python, selenium, filepath, rawstring

I am trying to give the file path in C# which contains special/escape characters. I am new to C#. please help me in defining the file path as `raw string literals.`

Following is path (`\t` has spl meaning):

> IE_DRIVER_PATH = "C:\software\selenium\temp\drivers\64"

In python we use it as follows (using `r` - to treat it as raw stiring):

> IE_DRIVER_PATH = r"C:\software\selenium\temp\drivers\64"

similarly, In java, we use `double slashes`.

please help me in defining the same in C#. As of now, I am getting the error which says that file does not exist, though the file is present in the folder.

Comment: @tigerhawkt3, as you mentioned, it is indeed duplicate, but I only got to know once you shared the link to the original question as I couldn't find it before I posted this question. I searched with keyword `C#, raw strings` but I didn't find the question and I am not aware of the terminology `verbatim`. so, it is just another way of finding what I want from existing python knowledge :).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In C#, you can either use double slashes (like in Java), or you can use `@` instead of `r` to create a verbatim string literal:

```
string IE_DRIVER_PATH = @"C:\software\selenium\temp\drivers\64";
```